# Adding new contact using mailgun in rails

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build app where users can subscribe for new updates. 
My mailer is configurated with mailgun. Everything works fine except when I try to add new user with this method (as in official document):     http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#mailing-lists.
Honestly I have no idea how to send email adress from form directly to add_list_member(mail) without saving it to my database.
I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two fields in your form

   1. Name
   2. Email
2. On Form's submission you send the input from the user to your backend for processing.
3. The backend takes the form's input, makes a few check to ensure the email is correct and not mispelled.
4. If the above is successful your backend pushes the email address and name to a mailing list, for reference that's something which you can create with the API or from the control panel (https://www.mailgun.com/cp/lists?domain=YOURDOMAIN.COM)
5. Then you just email the address provided in the email list

Comment: Thank you for response . I already solved that using ActiveModel.